# How to make sure that selectlist items belong to the same SelectListGroup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist, optgroup, selectlistitem

I am experimenting with the `<optgroup>` element and am trying to make several items belong to the same **optgroup**.

My code:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetStatsView()
    {
        var users = await _administrationServiceAPI.GetPersons();
        var tanks = await _administrationServiceAPI.GetTanks();


        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var u in users.Payload)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem {Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString(), Group = new SelectListGroup {Name = "Users"} };
            list.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var u in tanks.Payload)
        {
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem { Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString(), Group = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Tanks" } };
            list.Add(item);
        }

        @ViewBag.MyList = list;

        return View("StatsView");
    }
```

view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyList")
```

result:

[image]

Desiered result is:

**Users**

UserName

UserName

UserName

**Tanks**

Tank

Tank

Tank

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, you need to reuse the `SelectListGroup`. Just use it like this:

```
    var usersGroup = new SelectListGroup {Name = "Users"};
    foreach (var u in users.Payload)
    {
        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem {Text = u.Name, Value = u.Id.ToString(), Group = usersGroup };
        list.Add(item);
    }
```

And of course similarly for Tanks.

It does not matter that the name is the same, an instance used must be the same in various items to group them into single `optgroup`.

Comment: Happens even to the best. At least you got a laugh out of it :)